# What is the appropriate role for container registry in order to push and pull docker images from the GCR?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform, docker-image, google-container-registry

`"roles/storage.admin"` , `"roles/artifactregistry.admin"` .
Which of these roles has access over Google container registry.

`"roles/containerregistry.admin"`, Does this role actually exists. Can it access container registry if exists.

Trying to assign roles for service account through terraform.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use this Container Registry Service Agent (roles/containerregistry.ServiceAgent). The properties include the following:

- pubsub.topics.publish
- storage.objects.get
- storage.objects.getIamPolicy
- storage.objects.list

For more details and reference regarding the roles, you may check these documentations.[1][2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-agents-roles

[2] https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/map-roles

Comment: Yeah this may be right. but it has warning that service agents are having wide range of accesses. Can you confirm me here on one thing. storage.admin is also having the same access as containerregistry.serviceAgent. So I think storage.admin can have access to gcr.

Comment: According to the document, roles/storage.admin states that it grants full control of buckets and objects. This will only be applied to an individual bucket. The control applies only to the specified bucket and objects within that specific bucket.